# Influxdb: Query to create a list from some values

Tags: sql, select, influxdb, dummy-data

In InfluxDB, how can I create a list of strings/values by using a "SELECT" statement or any other "query" ?

My question is same as this question: [mysql fake select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937523/mysql-fake-select)
But, for `Influxdb`.

I'm using latest version of InfluxDB which is 1.2.4

Comment: which influxdb version you are using ?

Comment: @tom latest i.e. 1.2.4

Answer (score 1):

As of now , there is no IN operator support in influxdb .

Lets say I want to run the query like this -

```
 select value from measurement where key in ('903','965' ,'890') group by key limit 10 offset 0;
```

this can be done in a way like these -

**OR**

```
 select value from measurement where key='903' or key='965' or key='890' group by key limit 10 offset 0;
```

**Regex**

```
 select value from measurement where key=~ /^903$|^965$|^890$/ group by key limit 10 offset 0;
```

However, the above way is unindexed , so I will update my answer once influxdb start supporting `IN` operator .

Let me know , if this way around does not work for you and I will try to update it .

Comment: this what I was looking for initially it was working as 'like' operator , but after adding ^ $ gives the correct result.